# Weird override problem with Fluent NHibernate and .NET 4

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, .net-4.0

I recently [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922965/how-do-i-use-fluent-nhibernate-with-net-4-0) about using Fluent NHibernate with .NET 4 - I solved that problem, but met a new one.

**Summary**
My main problem (at the moment) is configuring the database. I'm following [this guide](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Getting_started#Your_first_project), but trying to work against SQL Server 2008 Express instead, as that's what I'll be using and thus what I need to learn.

**The failing code:**

```
public static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
{
    return Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("mssql")))
        .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Program>())
        .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg).Create(true, true))
        .BuildSessionFactory();
}
```

When I try to run my application, I get the following exception on the last line (`.BuildSessionFactory()`):

> Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: 'FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException.GetObjectData(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)'. Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the method being overriden.

**What is causing this?**

Comment: I have posted your question to Flune NHibernate mailing list. Hopefully they can help with it.

http://groups.google.com/group/fluent-nhibernate/browse_thread/thread/ae4013d711d2e4ad?hl=en

Comment: just updated my answer, check out the new link

Comment: Did you actually make it work? The solution below fixed the first problem, but then I got further problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697795/using-fluentnhibernate-with-net4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [Microsoft Connect issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=464751):

> Security attributes need to be
>   re-applied on types that derive from
>   other types that also have security
>   attributes.

Maybe [`FluentConfigurationException`](http://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/blob/master/src/FluentNHibernate/Cfg/FluentConfigurationException.cs) needs to apply a `[SecurityPermission]` attribute to its `GetObjectData()` method.

Else check out [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/peterblum/archive/2009/11/06/typeloadexception-based-on-security-transparent-code-level-2.aspx).

**EDIT**: The [final solution](http://groups.google.com/group/fluent-nhibernate/msg/c0e4613434bb433f) was adding `[SecurityCritical]` to [`FluentConfigurationException.GetObjectData()`](http://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/blob/master/src/FluentNHibernate/Cfg/FluentConfigurationException.cs)

Comment: OK - but this is a class defined in the FluentNHibernate assembly. Should I take this as a bug in FluentNHibernate (that I can fix in my own copy of the source) or as a problem in my implementation of FNH?

Comment: I looked at the source for System.Exception (see link below) and added the same attribute to FluentConfigurationException in my local copy, but it didn't help. Now that I read the error message again, it seems more like some other type is inheriting FluentConfigurationException, without the correct permissions, but I can't figure out where.

Link to source: http://labs.developerfusion.co.uk/SourceViewer/browse.aspx?assembly=SSCLI&namespace=System&type=Exception

Comment: Thanks for the update! I looked in the blog post and did what it suggested (added the attribute to `AssemblyInfo.cs`) but it didn't help. I'll keep an eye on that news group question =)

Comment: Thanks for the info, see http://groups.google.com/group/fluent-nhibernate/browse_thread/thread/ae4013d711d2e4ad for the fix. Not sure when the code will be merged into the main line.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! I will try this out as soon as I can on my local copy of the FNH source and keep you posted.