# log4net and .net Framework 4.0

Tags: .net-4.0, log4net

I was having issues in log4net when I updated my solutions to .net 4.0 , and then I downloaded the source of it and built log4net and targeted it to .net 4.0 and used it in my projects.

Initially when I referred log4net that is targeted to run time 2.0 it complied and run the application but log did not work.

Now when I run my project with log4net targeted to .net 4.0 I get the error `"The type initializer for 'Log4NetTest.TestLog' threw an exception."`

Any Idea how to solve this?

Edit: this is the inner exception:

```
InnerException: System.TypeLoadException Message=Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member:  
'log4net.Util.ReadOnlyPropertiesDictionary.GetObjectData(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)'.  
Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the method being overriden.
  Source=log4net
  TypeName=log4net.Util.ReadOnlyPropertiesDictionary.GetObjectData(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)
  StackTrace:
    at log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy..ctor(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    at log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy..ctor() in C:\src\Repository\Hierarchy\Hierarchy.cs:line 150
```

Comment: Look at what the nested exception is - see what exception the type initializer is, and that will help you to diagnose it.

Comment: Jon, I Added the Inner Exception in the question

Comment: Hi,

I Fixed it by adding [assembly: System.Security.SecurityRules(System.Security.SecurityRuleSet.Level1)] to log4net AssemblyInfo but now its not logging

Comment: log4net is *not* officially supported on 4.0 yet - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-233

Answer (score 4):

> In the log4net source code, add a [SecurityCritical] attribute to the 
>   Util.ReadOnlyPropertiesDictionary.GetObjectData method and build.

Just compiled the source for target framework 4.0 (not client). Source code of version 1.2.11 already contains this attribute, but be sure to use 'NET_4_0' as a compiler argument. Otherwise, this attribute will not be added.

Comment: The project that I downloaded from Apache.org had NET_4_0 defined in Debug configuration only. Had to add it to Release manually.

Comment: I have just added NET_4_0 for release configuration in 1.2.11 and it works! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I've found a compiled version of log4net for .NET client profile here:

http://gosheg.blogspot.com/2011/04/log4net-in-net-40-c-applications-net.html

Comment: Thanks! saved me reading all those blogs explaining how to download source and tweak like they did, instead of simply adding a `download here` on the top of page :)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

In the log4net source code, add a [SecurityCritical] attribute to the Util.ReadOnlyPropertiesDictionary.GetObjectData method and build.

There might be some other things you'll need to do to get it to build for the 4.0 framework.

See this post:

[Weird override problem with Fluent NHibernate and .NET 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924814/weird-override-problem-with-fluent-nhibernate-and-net-4)

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the similar issue by simply updating the Log4Net package from Visual Studio package manager.

Thanks,
Khachatur

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed it by adding [assembly: `System.Security.SecurityRules(System.Security.SecurityRuleSet.Level1)]` 
to log4net AssemblyInfo but now its not logging

Comment: adding this as an answer as i couldn't mark my comment as an answer